# TortoiseSVN - add folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to add a new folder to the SVN project using TortoiseSVN. Is this a correct way to do this?

1) Make a checkout - this will download the project to my computer (if I change/delete something - won't this affect the svn files?)

2) Drag the folder, right-click, add - this will add the folder to the svn.

Is this all?

Thanks! I don't want to mess anything up, sorry for this kind of question.

Comment: If you want to add a new foder to the project, you create it at the location where you want (first it gets flagged with a questionmark) and choose *add* from the *TortoiseSvn* menu. Afterwards you have to *commit* these changes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way! Glad you came. If you find it helpful, stick around, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and enjoy the community!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think you've basically got the right idea. But just to be clear, the steps are:

1. Checkout a working copy (WC)
2. In your WC, create a new folder (using whatever means your operating system offers; `mkdir`, "New Folder", whatever..)
3. Right-click on the folder, and from the Subversion menu, choose "Add"
4. Commit to repository

Comment: 1. which means - export -> checkout, or just clicking checkout without anything related on the computer?

Comment: Simply navigate to the folder where you want the WC and just choose Checkout. [see the docs here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html)